# Science fiction short story about an old man who builds a time machine to tell his deceased father goodbye before he himself dies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

From a Reddit discussion several years ago concerning the [most creative use of time travel](https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/9im7r1/most_creative_use_of_time_travel/), a user named punkwalrus posted the following:

> A short story from a SF&F literary magazine long out of print. It was
> a story about a guy obsessed with building a time machine, and spent
> his entire life on it. It's from the point of view of a young
> assistant, and starts off as a rant about how horrible this man was.
> The guy was stealing money for his work, involved in dubious mafia
> connections, and falsifying defense money to fund his operation.
>
> Finally, he makes it happen, but is barely alive because of his age
> and failing health, and has to be helped by his assistant because now
> the inventor is wheelchair bound. They walk in the past, which is the
> early 1970s, to a hospital somewhere in genetic suburbia. He wheels
> the inventor to a room, where a man on life support is alone in a bed.
>
> The frail inventor gets up, hobbles to the man, and hugs him.
> "Goodbye, daddy." is all he says through his tears.
>
> They return to the present, where the inventor destroys the machine,
> all his notes, and then dies.
>
> I still tear up over it.

He never mentioned the story title or who wrote it. Since he is still active on Reddit, I sent him a message a while back asking about the story, but I never received a reply. I've searched for it myself without success.